# Can I send a silent, no UI, foreground push notification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

As part of our sync solution I'm looking at ways the server can notify the device that there's new data. Websockets is an obvious choice but push notifications might be even easier, if it can do what we want. We just want the server, in a reasonably timely manner, to notify the device that there's new data. But only if the app is in the foreground. Background notifications are not appropriate in this case because a) Apple limits the number, and b) we don't require the app to be notified if it's in the background. When it comes to the foreground the first thing it will do is ask if there's new data.

With APNs can I send an always-silent, no UI, ignored in the background push notification?

To be clear, I'm not asking about background notifications. I want the app to be notified **only** when it's in the foreground. And I don't want any UI. I just want the app to notice and then do its thing. But only when it's in the foreground. If it's in the background, I don't want the notification to appear in the UI and I don't want the app to even respond.

Anyone had success with this with APNs? If this isn't possible with APNs, what have you used for this?

Comment: There is a form of notification in order to inform the app that there are new data to be downloaded, it does not show any UI to the user or alert. There is a specific payload for this and the link on the below. I think it works normally in foreground and when you receive the notification, you can test if the app is in foreground or background (In the case here, the background notification would be that the notification would be processed in the background)  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app

Comment: Thanks @ClaudioCastro, but, as I mentioned in the question, background notifications are not appropriate in my case. Following that link, note the first line in Overview: "If your app’s server-based content changes infrequently or at irregular intervals, you can use background notifications to notify your app when new content becomes available. " In my case it would not be infrequent. And Apple limits background notifications. And in my case I don't need background notifications. When the app comes to the foreground it will sync and that is fine for my case.

Comment: I believe that in this case the background is because the notification runs a background process, not because the app is in the background. But that's okay, you already said you don't want infrequently , in which case you can give up notification, because in the documentation, apple informs you that the delivery of notification is not guaranteed.